# $\sum \frac{b_j}{j^2}$ converge or diverge

Tags: sequences-and-series

if $b_j>0$ and $\sum b_j$ convege does

$\sum \frac{b_j}{j^2}$ converge or diverge

I think it converges because

$\sum \frac{b_j}{j^2} < \sum b_j$

Thus by comparison test converges.

Comment: Your argument is correct.

Comment: @Crostul, what if some of $b_j$ are negative and the series does not converge absolutely?

Comment: @BenFrankel **if $b_j>0$**

Comment: @kingW3, Whoops I didn't notice that. Then yes, the argument is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test). Provided that $\sum_{n\geq 1}b_n $ is a convergent series,
$$ B_n = \sum_{j=1}^{n} b_j $$
is bounded, and $j\mapsto\frac{1}{j^2}$ is a decreasing function with limit zero.

In such a way we may also drop the assumption $b_j>0$.

Comment: observe that $|b_j|<1$ for all but finitely many $j$  so $|b_j/j^2|<1/j^2$ for all but finitely many $j$..

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

By Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$\sum_{j}\frac{b_j}{j^2}\leq \sqrt{\sum_{j}b_j^2}\sqrt{\sum_{j}\frac{1}{j^4}}$$

Comment: cute way do do it...................